# Use Kotlin compiler options for test sources in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, compiler-options

In my test sources I want to use some experimental Kotlin compiler feature to not see the lint warnings and errors for them in Android Studio. For example, I want to apply the following Kotlin options to all test sources.

```
compileTestKotlin {
  kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs += [
        '-Xopt-in=kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime',
        '-Xopt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi',
    ]
  }
}
```

([source](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine/tree/0.2.1#experimental-api-usage))

Out of the box this doesn't work in an Android project, because there is no `compileTestKotlin` method. According to the [kotlin-android Gradle plugin docs](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.4.10/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/Module.md#kotlin-android), it should be possible to do this for compile*VariantName*Kotlin in an `afterEvaluate` block, e.g.:

```
afterEvaluate {
  compileDebugUnitTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
      freeCompilerArgs += [
        '-Xopt-in=kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime',
        '-Xopt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi',
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

(and similar for `compileReleaseUnitTestKotlin`)

Although this works (builds and test run and pass just fine), there seems to be no effect in Android Studio: usages of the experimental compiler features are still marked with warnings/errors.

How do I enable these compiler features for my test sources in such a way that AS recognizes and uses them?

Comment: I wonder: is this simply an Android Studio feature that is unavailable, being developed, or bugged? If so, is there some issue somewhere that I can follow or contribute my use case to, if unknown (I can hardly imagine)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This worked for me on Android Studio 4.2.2, AGP version 4.2.0, Kotlin version 1.5.10:

```
android {
    testOptions {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += [
                '-Xopt-in=kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime',
                '-Xopt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi',
            ]
        }
    }
}
```